# How to overlay a jpg onto a google earth image?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, overlay, google

I have produced a model from an online engine [image: potential], and it is in a google earth picture. I want to georeference the below picture[image: 349.jpg] and apply the boundaries here on my google earth image. I'm using QGIS2.2. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the georeferencer to get the jpeg in the correct position and then digitise the lines/boundaries so that you dont have to have the jpeg in the model anymore

Comment: A couple of questions more:

1) im confused with the georeferencing tool. How do i interpret the degree coordinates? So 9'50 is 950000km?

2) How do i digitise the jpg?

Thanks a lot! I'm still very new to QGIS.

Comment: @user32389 Please check the existing questions and open new ones if you don't find anything that helps.

Comment: If you have a model with the right coordinates then you can just load the raster/jpeg and instead of manually inserting the X and Y, you can use the map canvas to match up points that are the same.

Comment: for digitising you can add new vector layers.

Comment: Like underdark has pointed out, it is probably easier to check existing questions. The should be a guide somewhere too, telling you how to use the digitising and georeferencer tools properly